# multiple checkbox logic with search function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, logic

I have 3 checkboxes that I will be using for search options. Now the user can select any number of them for searching. My question is: `Is there a more convenient way to write out the logic for the search, rather than doing an if/else or boolean check for for every combination?` 3 checkboxes isn't too bad, but I could see an issue with say 5+ checkboxes. Would there be a better way to implement a search function with multiple options?

This is what I am currently doing:

```
    public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, string searchFilter)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "year" : "";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        ViewBag.CurrentFilterSelection = searchFilter;

        var resolutions = from c in db.AllResolutions select c;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            resolutions = resolutions.Where(c => c.ResolutionYear.Contains(searchString) || c.ResolutionTextShort.Contains(searchString) || c.ResDescription.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "date":
                resolutions = resolutions.OrderByDescending(c => c.ResDate);
                break;
            case "year":
                resolutions = resolutions.OrderByDescending(c => c.ResolutionYear);
                break;
            case "number":
                resolutions = resolutions.OrderByDescending(c => c.ResolutionNumber);
                break;
            default:
                resolutions = resolutions.OrderBy(c => c.ResolutionYear).ThenBy(c => c.ResolutionNumber);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 25;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(resolutions.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

I am currently searching the database in 3 separate columns and returning the results that contain `searchString`. I would like to be able to have the user select whether or not they want to limit the columns they are searching for

`ie: I want to search for all 2018 resolutions or I want to search all 2018 resolutions with the keyword here`

Comment: could you provide a bit more details? what kind of search? database query or so? add some code how you use the values

Comment: @JarekKożdoń I have added what I am currently doing for searching. I am just searching multiple database fields to see if `searchString` is within 3 different columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most clear way to do that would be something like that:

```
    if(searchForYear)
    {
        resolutions = resolutions.Where(c => c.ResolutionYear.Contains(searchString));
    }
    if (searchForTextShort)
    {
        resolutions = resolutions.Where(c => c.ResolutionTextShort.Contains(searchString));
    }
    //and so on for each other checkbox value
```

so basically: yes, the only way is the "list" of "ifs" but you can split your query building like above so the code is still readable and easy to maintain

Comment: I thought that was what I would have to do.

Comment: BTW this is also more efficient than trying to add those ifs or elses into single .Where - query builder will only build sql based on wanted fitlers without any unnecessary code for those elements you don't want